# SQL - WHERE clause Return results with next working day

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

I seem to be asking a lot of SQL questions at the moment. (I would normally write a program to sort the data into a report table, however at the moment that is not possible, and needs to be done using SQL)

**The Question**
I need a where clause that returns results with the next working day. i.e. Monday 01/01/01 the next working day would be Tuesday 02/01/01 which could be achieved with a simple date add. However on a Friday 05/01/01 the next working day is Monday 08/01/01. Is there anything built in to help cope with this easily?

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with a simple day check and add 3 days rather than one if its a Friday. However, do you need to take into consideration public holidays though?

Comment: Ideally yes, however if it is too complex then that is not important.

Comment: A simple PublicHolidays table with fixed dates would be simple to select against; expand @Pinal's UDF (from @Vinko's answer) to bump the date by 1 (in whatever direction you're going) for each match. A more detailed holiday design is probably unnecessary.

Comment: Its a lot simpler then i first thought, the report is only run/created on week days. So all i need to do is work out if its a friday and add 3 days, else i add one.

Answer (score 4):

The key is to use the [DATEPART(weekday,@date)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms174420.aspx) function, it'll return the day of the week, so if it's saturday or sunday you just add one or two to the current date to get the desired result.

You can create a user defined function to do so easily, for example [Pinal Dave](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/07/23/sql-server-udf-function-to-get-previous-and-next-work-day-exclude-saturday-and-sunday/) has this

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_GetPrevNextWorkDay (@dtDate DATETIME, @strPrevNext VARCHAR(10))
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @intDay INT
DECLARE @rtResult DATETIME
SET @intDay = DATEPART(weekday,@dtDate)
--To find Previous working day
IF @strPrevNext = 'Previous'
IF @intDay = 1
SET @rtResult = DATEADD(d,-2,@dtDate)
ELSE
IF @intDay = 2
SET @rtResult = DATEADD(d,-3,@dtDate)
ELSE
SET @rtResult = DATEADD(d,-1,@dtDate)
--To find Next working day
ELSE
IF @strPrevNext = 'Next'
IF @intDay = 6
SET @rtResult = DATEADD(d,3,@dtDate)
ELSE
IF @intDay = 7
SET @rtResult = DATEADD(d,2,@dtDate)
ELSE
SET @rtResult = DATEADD(d,1,@dtDate)
--Default case returns date passed to function
ELSE
SET @rtResult = @dtDate
RETURN @rtResult
END
GO
```

Comment: A small improvement would be to use a BIT type instead of VARCHAR for the direction, and have 1 for "next" and 0 for "previous", avoiding the need for the third case.

Comment: From an internationalization perspective this UDF could also take a calendar or region code to lookup the appropriate weekday definition - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workweek

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.uf_GetNextWorkingDay (@givenDate DATETIME)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @workingDate DATETIME

    IF (DATENAME(dw , @givenDate) = 'Friday')
        BEGIN
             SET @workingDate = DATEADD(day, 3, @givenDate)
        END
    ELSE IF (DATENAME(dw , @givenDate) = 'Saturday')
        BEGIN
             SET @workingDate = DATEADD(day, 2, @givenDate)
        END
    ELSE 
        BEGIN
             SET @workingDate = DATEADD(day, 1, @givenDate)
        END

    RETURN @workingDate
END
```

A good article http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2005/02/14/1685.aspx

Answer (score 1):

All Credit to Cashif -- I modified his to include a Holiday table (`tblHolidays` with a date field `HolDate`) which is very lightweight -- about 10 rows a year if you're lucky enough to get that many days off!

My version returns `date` type (which I find easier to work with). I also run thru this more than once -- if Thursday is your startday and Friday is a holiday, you have to again add 2 more days to get to Monday (or the next working day). Then it checkes to make sure the next week doesn't start with a holiday.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetNextWorkingDay] (@givenDate DATE)
RETURNS DATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @workingDate DATETIME
    IF (DATENAME(dw , @givenDate) = 'Friday')
    BEGIN
         SET @workingDate = DATEADD(day, 3, @givenDate)
    END
    ELSE IF (DATENAME(dw , @givenDate) = 'Saturday')
    BEGIN
         SET @workingDate = DATEADD(day, 2, @givenDate)
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
         SET @workingDate = DATEADD(day, 1, @givenDate)
    END

    while ((Select  count(*) from tblHolidays where holdate = @workingDate) > 0)
    begin
        set @workingDate = dateadd(dd,1,@WorkingDate)
    end
    -- if adding a day makes it a Saturday, add 2 more to get to Monday (and test to make sure the week doesn't start with a holiday)
    IF (DATENAME(dw , @workingDate) = 'Saturday')
    BEGIN
         SET @workingDate = DATEADD(day, 2, @workingDate)
    END


    while ((Select  count(*) from tblHolidays where holdate = @workingDate) > 0)
    begin
        set @workingDate = dateadd(dd,1,@WorkingDate)
    end
    RETURN @workingDate
END
```

... of course you **should** refactor so the code doesn't repeat, and include a while clause to repeat only as many times as needed to get to a working day, but I have a deadline... that'll be for another less hectic day.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did for a one-off application:

```
        WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Holidays WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR, HolidayDate,101) = CONVERT(VARCHAR,@DateVariable 101 ) OR DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @DateVariable)='SATURDAY' OR DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @DateVariable)='SUNDAY')
        BEGIN
            SET @DateVariable = DateAdd(day,1,@DateVariable)
            PRINT @DateVariable -- If you want
        END
```

Note that, our `Holidays` table stores all holidays for the past and future years.

Comment: I like this a lot. nice, simple and elegant

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a simple case statement.

```
select case when datepart(dw, getdate()) >= 6 then getdate() + (9 - datepart(dw, getdate())) else getdate() + 1 end
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a calendar table. Getting the next working days is not so simple if you need to account for holidays other than the weekend. The table basically contains just two columns Date and an integer field indicating whether it is a working/non working day- but there can be other columns for - example quarter etc as well.

This table is populated once a year and then maintained as necessary. Getting the result for next working day then becomes as simple as a query like this.

```
SELECT field1,filed2 from your table T where your date_Field = (SELECT min(date) From calendar table where WorkingDay = 1 and date > GetDate())
```

/P

Answer (score 0):

How about somethin like this?

```
select * from table
where (date = dateadd(dd,1,@today) and datepart(weekday,@today) not in (6,0) ) --its not friday or saturday 
or    (date = dateadd(dd,2,@today) and datepart(weekday,@today) = 0) -- its saturday 
or    (date = dateadd(dd,3,@today) and datepart(weekday,@today) = 6) --its friday
```

the date attribute should have the same time as @today or else you have to also use between

Answer (score 0):

It's been basically answered above, but it took me a while to get it and I thought maybe this will help somebody. Is used a simple CASE-WHEN.

This is a check in order to find out which days are weekdays

```
DATEPART(dw, date) -> MON through FRI = 1,2,3,4,5    SAT = 6,     SUN = 7
```

This is the CASE-WHEN:

```
CASE
    WHEN DATEPART(weekday, date) <= 5 THEN date       -- weekdays, no change
    WHEN DATEPART(weekday, date)  = 6 THEN date + 2   -- SAT + 2 = MON
    WHEN DATEPART(weekday, date)  = 6 THEN date + 1   -- SUN + 1 = MON
END AS 'WEEKDAY_DATES'
```

Check, if the statement actually gets you weekdays only:

```
CASE
    WHEN DATEPART(weekday, date) <= 5 THEN DATENAME(weekday, date)
    WHEN DATEPART(weekday, date)  = 6 THEN DATENAME(weekday, date + 2)
    WHEN DATEPART(weekday, date)  = 6 THEN DATENAME(weekday, date + 1)
END AS 'WEEKDAY_NAMES'
```